# Codeigniter - Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string - Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to format a date and it shows me the following messages:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

**I have tried all these, and continue the messages.**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', '01/01/2017');

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', '01/01/2017')));

$start_date = new DateTime("2017-01-01 20:00:00");
$end_date   = new DateTime("2018-05-05 22:00:00");
$between    = $start_date->diff($end_date);

echo 'between: '.$between->y.' years, <br>' 
                   .$between->m.' months, <br>' 
                   .$between->d.' days <br>'
                   .$between->days.' days <br>';

echo "<pre>"; print_r($between);
```

**This function to implement:**

```
public function between_days($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $start_date = strtotime($start_date);
    $start_date = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
    $end_date = strtotime($end_date);
    $between = abs($end_date - $start_date);
    $total = $between / 86400;
    $days = intval($total);
    return $days;
}
```

Comment: The code is working fine.

Comment: https://eval.in/788224

Comment: If correct, it works perfectly but it shows me those messages, it is in codeiginiter nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

```
Severity: Notice

Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

This notice occure due to

> echo date('Y-m-d', '01/01/2017');

You have to remove above line.

Comment: It is necessary to use it as in the description

Comment: if you want to use that first line use it like this: `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01/01/2017'));`

Comment: You should not use string as second parameter in date function. You have to pass timestemp value as a second second parameter. More description here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)